# Is it appropriate to contact a professor about paid summer research before beginning PhD?

Tags: phd, research-undergraduate

I apologize if this is specific to the field or professor, I'm still figuring out academia.StackExchange. Just flag me if it's a bad question. If it matters, I'm studying Electrical and Computer Engineering.

I've recently been accepted to some Ph.D. programs. I also happen to have no internships lined up for this summer. Is it appropriate to ask professors if I can begin (paid) research with them this summer before I begin as a Ph.D. candidate?

Comment: Do you mean to ask professors under whose supervision you intend to do your PhD, or in general?

Comment: I am entering with just a BS, so I think I have some time before deciding an advisor. However, I would certainly ask someone who I'm interested in advising me.

Comment: It's likely that you can't be employed as a research assistant until you are formally enrolled.  If you were admitted for the fall semester you might have to request that this be changed to the summer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can ask. If the professor has grant funds and a need for someone to fill a slot then you might be successful. It needn't be the person you intend as your advisor, and if you are entering with just a BS then it is unlikely that you would choose a final advisor so soon.

But asking is not a problem.

However, you might also consider that taking a bit of time off might be better overall, to avoid burnout that can arise after an intense degree program. If the money is essential, however, don't hesitate to say that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have considered taking the summer off, so I will definitely think about that.

Answer (score 0):

If this were to happen, most likely you would be hired on as a temporary employee rather than literally "starting early"; effectively there is little difference although the pay rate might be different than your typical stipend.

I'd say there is no harm in asking but be clear what your expectations and commitments are (you're looking for summer employment, not necessarily committing to joining the lab; you understand this may not be possible).

For what it's worth, I did something quite similar before my Ph.D., though I was instead employed at my *previous* institution, the one I just graduated from, working with an advisor I did unpaid undergraduate research with. You might also look to this as a possibility if it makes sense. One benefit to the person paying you, in this case, is that you're already onboarded/trained in some way, so they can get some immediate help from you that's worth paying for. It's harder to see the direct benefit in employing someone for just ~3 months; they're not likely to accomplish much in that time, and in particular, if they're still considering other labs it might not be worth the investment; labs are often pretty tight on funds.